# Copying user-submitted data to the next empty row on a separate worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to using VBA/excel for anything more than the basics.

The problem I am faced with is:

**Background**
*Every day a massive excel table must be updated. This entails entering a series of data values on the next empty row at the bottom of the table. This data is then used for a variety of other purposes (weekly reports, populating an Access database, etc).*

Some of the data must be converted to different units. I would like to automate the process somewhat such that a user simply has to fill in a few fields and the data table is automatically populated.

I'd like to have the user fields on one worksheet and the raw data table on another worksheet. Ideally, a one-click macro could generate a new row of data in the raw data table based on the user-inputted data on a different worksheet.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. If this is an inappropriate question in any way, let me know what else I should provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your actual workbook, I'm going to provide the solution for a simplified example.  Let's assume the user inputs the new data values in cells A1 and B1 on Sheet1.
You want these values to be added to the next empty row on Sheet2.

Once the user enters the values, you can run a macro with this code:

```
Dim intNewRow As Long
intNewRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row + 1
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(intNewRow, 1) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(intNewRow, 2) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2).Value
```

This is probably oversimplified, but you can change units by adding the mathematical operations at the end of the formulas.  The key I think you were looking for was finding the next empty row.  The second line of code is what does that for you and assigns it to the variable intNewRow.

Comment: I should point out, this assumes Sheet2 has your table of data starting in cell A1 and there are not any empty cells in column A until after the table ends.

Comment: thank you for the feedback - with a little fiddling it works just like I want it to!